# Calculate cell number in the formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to reference a cell. Sheet2!D1 and the next row will have Sheet2!D10. Instead of writing this I want to write Sheet2!DRow()+8.

What's the correct syntax of calculating row()+8 and then appending it to D?

Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution suggested by @MohammadYusuf will work.

However `INDIRECT` is a volatile function which means it will recalculate any time anything on the worksheet recalculates and may slow things down.

A non-volatile equivalent can be constructed using `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D,IF(ROWS($1:1)=1,1,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*10),1)
```

As you fill down, the `ROWS($1:1)` argument will increment and produce your series of row numbers.

An alternative, if you have Office 365, would be:

```
    =LET(x,INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D,SEQUENCE(100,,1,10),1),
        IF( x="","",x))
```

entered into a single cell and it will Spill down the results

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...  *(LibreOffice uses `.` instead of `!` apparently)*

`=OFFSET(Sheet2.D1,0,0)`
`=OFFSET(Sheet2.D1,8,0)`

... is another option.

The second argument (i.e. 0 and 8) may be replaced by `(ROW()-n)*8` for indexing depending on where the formula resides, n=1 for first row.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, we can do it like so:

`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet2!D",9*(ROW()-1)+1))`